# First time login throws 401 Unaauthorized Access On Android Kotlin

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, kotlin

I am developing an android application that requires authentication (Login).

- When a user logs in, A bearer token jwt, is generated from my backend
- I store this token using SharedPreference
- Using Retrofit OkHttp Interceptor, I add an interceptor that requires this saved bearer token in order to access authorized endpoints.

The problem is

- When a user logs in for the first time, and visit any authorised endpoint, it throws a 401 - UnAuthorized. The user have to close the app, then open it (Without logging in) the endpoints start working, Returning 200. (Meanwhile, I did a check and the bearer token is been sent and is saved to the app) but for some reason for the first time, the endpoints returns 401. Unless, I close the app and open it, then the endpoints throws 200.

The backend guys says its from my app, because the bearer token is sent and it works first time on Post Man.
The backend uses NodeJs.

**LoginActivity**

```
if (it.data?.status == "success") {

   //get the token and store it
   val token = it.data.token

   //store token
   PreferenceHelper.storeToken = token

  //store user session
  PreferenceHelper.isLoggedInSeller = true

  //go to home activity
  val intent = Intent(this, SellerHomeActivity::class.java)
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
  startActivity(intent)           

}
```

**PreferenceHelper**

```
object PreferenceHelper {

private const val NAME = "session"
private const val MODE = Context.MODE_PRIVATE
private lateinit var preferences: SharedPreferences

//SharedPreferences variables
private val hasLoggedInSeller = Pair("isLoginSeller", false)
private val loginToken = Pair("login_token", "")


fun init(context: Context) {
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(NAME, MODE)
}

//an inline function to put variable and save it
private inline fun SharedPreferences.edit(operation: (SharedPreferences.Editor) -> Unit) {
    val editor = edit()
    operation(editor)
    editor.apply()
}

//check if seller has logged in
var isLoggedInSeller: Boolean
    get() = preferences.getBoolean(hasLoggedInSeller.first, hasLoggedInSeller.second)
    set(value) = preferences.edit {
        it.putBoolean(hasLoggedInSeller.first, value)
    }

//store login token for buyer
var storeToken: String?
    get() = preferences.getString(loginToken.first, loginToken.second)
    set(value) = preferences.edit {
        it.putString(loginToken.first, value)
    }
}
```

**AuthInterceptor**

```
class AuthInterceptor : Interceptor {

var  token = PreferenceHelper.storeToken

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

    val requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder()

    // If token has been saved, add it to the request
    token?.let {
        requestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $it")
    }


    return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
 }

}
```

**Retrofit**

```
 @Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(gson: Gson) : Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(EndPoints.BASE_URL)
    .client(
        OkHttpClient.Builder().also { client ->
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
            }
            client.addInterceptor(logging)
            client.addInterceptor(AuthInterceptor())
            client.connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            client.readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            client.protocols(Collections.singletonList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
        }.build()
    )
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build()
```

**Logout**

```
//remove session and token
PreferenceHelper.storeToken = ""
PreferenceHelper.isLoggedInSeller = false
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in `Interceptor`, move the `token` statement inside `intercept` method which will be triggered for every request else it would only be created once per instance and will continue to use the same token

```
class AuthInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder()
        PreferenceHelper.storeToken?.let {
            requestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $it")
        }
        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
    }
}
```